# has function in the helm template is not returning true

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a `values.yaml` file containing list variable like:

`excludePort: [32104, 30119]`

I am trying to use that in the helm template like:

```
{{ if has 32104 .Values.excludePort }}
```

But it seems to be not returning true. (The block after the condition is not executing. Any reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by a variable type mismatch.

```yaml
{{ kindOf (first .Values.excludePort) }}
```

output:

```
float64
```

You need to understand that the essence of helm rendering templates is to first parse the values.yaml file into map through golang, and the number will be deserialized to float64 type by default, which is determined by the underlying implementation of the golang language.

See this: [Go Decode](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode) 、[json package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal)

So the elements in the excludePort array is of type `float64` and 32104 is of type `int`

In order to get the desired result you need to implement this:

`{{- if has 32104.0 .Values.excludePort}}`

Of course, this is not a good implementation, because there is a precision problem caused by float, it is best to use a `string` to solve it.

Lisk this:

values.yaml

```yaml
excludePort: ["32104", "30119"]
```

template/xxx.yaml

```yaml
{{- if has "32104" .Values.excludePort}}
...
```